# Make Community's rollback war flag smarter

Tags: feature-request, flags, community-user

Community just flagged a question as a possible rollback war.

Looking at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13247996/revisions), there was a minor, non-contested edit when the second revision was made, and then the rest of the edits were rollbacks to previous versions because the OP couldn't make up his mind.

Community put the "possible rollback war" flag in the queue at version five.

In this case, this isn't a rollback war, and it's pretty obvious that it isn't.  Moderators don't need to be notified of this activity.

That said, if the rollbacks aren't from different users, the flag shouldn't be raised to the moderators.

Comment: OP's should be allowed to rollback & edit as much as they want. If they start [changing colors](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) and altering the actual question then a flag will be raised by one of the other users participating.

Comment: Isn't a rollback "war" the OP rolling back other people's edits? The OP rolling back their own edits shouldn't trigger a flag but it might still be useful to raise one if the OP is continually rolling back other people's.

Comment: @Ben He rolled back one of someone else's edit, but it wasn't anything contentious.  All the rollbacks after were him rolling back to the original version (the edit by someone else) or another of his versions.